# Why are the ads shown on StackExchange of StackExchange websites and apps only?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Why are the ads shown on SE about SE websites and its android app only? I don't think that'll earn SE something. I'd says that almost every time, the ad is about SE network website and only a few times about other websites like:ProofWiki, MIT OpenCourseWare, etc.
So why is it so?

Comment: Why should they advertise other sites? What's the gain to Stack Exchange exactly??

Comment: @ShadowWizard Who'll pay me if I show my website's ads on my website?

Comment: If you show *your* ads? Guess you'll pay yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So does SE pay SE?

Comment: Nope. SE is self advertising its own sites so people will get to know them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But then how do they earn money, if their major source of profit is advertising?

Comment: They do have external advertisements, shown in question pages for <200 rep users. They got sponsored tags.

Comment: Now when I finally understand what you mean, I found a proper dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've read that and the third point in the accepted answer talks about advertising.

Comment: No need for chat, ask here and others can answer as well. :)

Comment: But many users have >200 rep, so if they increase this limit to 500 or maybe 1000 rep, it would obviously increase their profit and it wouldn't harm us at all...In fact it would be better if SE earns more...More earning = Better Features.

Comment: Higher rep users still get _some_ ads, just not quite as much. I still see Rackspace ads from time to time. Plus, you'd be surprised at the number of users with rep > 200 (hint: not many).

Comment: @shauryagupta guess you can write a check or send cash to Stack Exchange if you're so worried but I really don't think they need it. With millions of unique visitors per day they're doing just fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm 15 and got no money...The day I start earning, I'll surely send one!